# Use `case` in an sql update statement with Jetbrains Exposed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have a table with two timestamp columns `error_started` and `last_error`. Is it possible to write an update statement with Jetbrains Exposed that will only set the `error_started` if it `is null`?

Been playing with variations of this without any luck. Seems to me like the `case()` construct is limited to working with non-nullable types?

```
with(SqlExpressionBuilder) {
    case()
        .When(MyTable.error_started.isNull(), timestampParam(timestamp))
        .Else(MyTable.error_started) // Compilation error here due to the column being nullable
}
```

Comment: The When case fires on isNull() , which doesn't that determine if it is or is not null, so true would be null, so it timestamps on the NULL case and not on the else?  Forgive me though I have not exposed kotlins before but in VB Isnull(thing) = true/false .. so just checking if that logic is the same here.